# How to change and store shopping cart quantity values in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a cart page on the site that loads list of items based on `JSON` products list and a `JSON` list of added cart items, which is loaded and stored in localStorage. I am not including all the code to not overload the question.

The problem is - for some reason only the last item actually saves the changed `quantity` value. If there are 2 items in the cart and I change the first one - after the refresh it becomes `quantity = 1` and it's `quantity` jumps to the next one.

```
let cart;

if (localStorage.getItem('cart') === null) {
    cart = [];
} else {
    cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
}

function loadCart() {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('get', 'data/products.json');
    request.onload = () => {
        try {
            const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            populateCart(json);

        } catch (e) {
            console.warn('Could not load products');
        }
    }

    request.send();
}

function populateCart(json) {
    let cartExists = false;
    cartSection.innerHTML = "";
    buttonsContainer.innerHTML = "";

    json.forEach((row) => {
        if (cart.filter(e => e.product_ID === row.product_ID).length > 0) {
            cartExists = true;

            objIndex = cart.findIndex((e => e.product_ID === row.product_ID));

            <...>

            const input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'number';
            input.value = cart[objIndex].quantity;
            input.id = row.product_ID;
            input.inputmode = 'numeric';
            input.min = '1';
            input.max = '100';
            input.oninput = function () {
                if (parseInt(this.value) > parseInt(this.max)) {
                    this.value = this.max;
                }
                else if (parseInt(this.value) < parseInt(this.min)) {
                    this.value = this.min;
                }
                else if (this.value === "") { this.value = this.min; }

                cart[objIndex].quantity = this.value;
                localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
            };

            <...>

        }
    });

<...>

}
```

Comment: I assume the problem is more likely to be found in the saving routine and not the one creating the product table. Have you checked if the JSON that is being received from the server contains quantities different from 1 for the other items? Not related: why not use `input.min=1;input.max=100;` and `input.value = parseInt(cart[objIndex].quantity;` and get rid of the remaining `parseInt(...)` calls?

Comment: @SaschaM78 json that I recieve from the server has no quantities, it is just a list of products to fill in the details if I find them in the cart, which is always in localStorage.

Comment: Could you extend your posted code above with the saving routine?

Comment: @SaschaM78 it's already there. `oninput` I restrict the value and assign it to `this.value` of the input field right after that I update that in the `quantity` field of `cart` array and update the localStorage with the updated `cart` array. The next refresh first it unpacks the `cart` array from localStorage (like here at the beginning) and all from the start.
I guess the problem is with current `objIndex`. I guess I should not search the `cart` array 2 times in a row, first to find if there any matches and then to find index. But still do not understand why it does not work.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes, missed that spot. Ah, now I think I found the error: `objIndex` is incremented for each element in the cart which would be correct. When the `input.oninput` event occurs, it will update the variable with the current `objIndex` which will always be the last entry. I'll create an example solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the `objIndex` and its use within the `input.oninput` event handler:

the variable gets updated in the loop and when the input change event occurs it will always point to the last element of the cart. A solution would be to create an object within the loop holding a reference to the current `objIndex` value and use this one in the input method:

```
...
input.max = '100';

// create an object containing the current ID
let product = {};
product.id = objIndex;
input.oninput = function() {
  if (parseInt(this.value) > parseInt(this.max)) {
    this.value = this.max;
  } else if (parseInt(this.value) < parseInt(this.min)) {
    this.value = this.min;
  } else if (this.value === "") {
    this.value = this.min;
  }

  // access the stored ID in the event handler:
  cart[product.id].quantity = parseInt(this.value);
}
```

Comment: You pushed me the right way and opened my mind :)) Actually the `objIndex` already holds that role that you showed with `product.id`, cause (correct me if I am wrong), the relative `objIndex` value should be stored in something like a closure of a function for each `oninput` of each product in a cart. Just... for some reason that `objIndex` was not declared by me before and write `let` to the left made it work. I am sorry man, that's mine pure blackout. But thank you so much for help!! :))

Comment: @John123 this sometimes still happens to me, even after 20 years of programming ;-). Nice it worked for you!